# Why do I get a message saying "attribute value missing" when using angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs

I am using code like this:

```
   <span translate translate-attr-title="QUESTIONS.INCORRECT">
```

But in Visual Studio 2015 it shows a green line under translate saying "attribute value missing".

Is there a way that I can fix this? I know it does not stop the code working but I would like it to not show as an "error" or show the green line.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems to make little difference, Angular uses the ng- prefix for directives so simply use ng-translate and this will sort the issue out for you.